# Java setMaximizedbounds not working properly on dual screen environment

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

1st Primary Monitor (left): **1680x1050** with **%100** text size

2nd Monitor (right): **1920x1080** with **%100** text size

Simply primary monitor has less resolution than secondary monitor.

I have a jframe (please see below test code) where **setUndecorated=true** and I do implement my own maximize window actions.
Simply, I do calculate screen insets for each monitor and maximize frame according to available space.
However, when it comes to secondary monitor, this fails. Screen do not cover whole screen although sizes are given according to monitor values.

Hint: Same code works in both scenarios in which both monitor has equal resolution or primary monitor has bigger resolution than secondary monitor.

Any idea, work-around?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrameTest frame = new FrameTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FrameTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener(this);
        addMouseListener(frameDragListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(frameDragListener);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Max");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (getExtendedState() == MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
                    setExtendedState(NORMAL);
                else {
                    setMaximizedBounds(getMaximizedBounds());
                    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(21, 21, 61, 34);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("X");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(92, 21, 43, 34);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
        setUndecorated(true);
    }

    public static class FrameDragListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private final JFrame frame;
        private Point mouseDownCompCoords = null;

        public FrameDragListener(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = null;
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDownCompCoords = e.getPoint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point currCoords = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            frame.setLocation(currCoords.x - mouseDownCompCoords.x, currCoords.y - mouseDownCompCoords.y);
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getMaximizedBounds() {

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
        
    

        Rectangle bounds = this.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
        Rectangle maxBounds = null;
        Insets screenInsets = this.getToolkit().getScreenInsets(this.getGraphicsConfiguration());
        
        //fails to have full screen in secondary monitor
        maxBounds = new Rectangle(
                screenInsets.left, 
                screenInsets.top,
                bounds.width - screenInsets.right - screenInsets.left,
                bounds.height - screenInsets.bottom - screenInsets.top);
        
        return maxBounds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8263086

That's a java bug and can be trackked above url